# How do I implement my own animation library in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

Let's say I want to use something like JQuery UI to write some animations when an element is added or removed from the DOM. I see in [this article](http://blog.aurelia.io/2015/07/17/animating-apps-with-aurelia-part-1/#howdoesaureliasupportanimations) that I could use the **animator** interface to write my own animations using the **enter** and **leave** functions. This same article uses the example of **view-slot.js** to show how this interface is utilized. I can even see this dependency being injected here, like this

```
import {Animator} from './animator';
...
constructor(anchor: Node, anchorIsContainer: boolean, animator?: Animator = Animator.instance) {
```

How can I supply my own implementation of the Animator interface here? I used the [Greensock aurelia plugin](https://github.com/gooy/aurelia-animator-greensock/blob/master/src/animator.js), which is another javascript animation library, as an example of how I might do this only to find that it's using its own version of **animator.js** with Greensock animations written into it. I was expecting to find something that would supply a custom implementation of the animator interface to the view-slot constructor but came up empty.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. You need to run `configureAnimator` on the templating engine which resides inside Aurelia's DI container. Below example is taken from animator-css which is an implementation of the animator interface. This piece of code runs during the startup process as a plugin.

```
export function configure(config: Object, callback?:(animator:CssAnimator) => void): void {
  let animator = config.container.get(CssAnimator);
  config.container.get(TemplatingEngine).configureAnimator(animator);
  if (typeof callback === 'function') { callback(animator); }
}
```

https://github.com/aurelia/animator-css/blob/master/src/index.js